# How do I add a column, preserving the existing columns, without listing them all?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to add a new column to an alias, preserving all the existing ones.

```
A = foreach A generate
  A.id as id, 
  A.date as date, 
  A.foo as foo, 
  A.bar as bar, 
  A.foo / A.bar as foobar;
```

Can I do that without listing all of them explicitly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, let's say you have an alias like:

```
A: {num1:int, num2:int}
```

and you want to calculate the sum while keeping `num1` and `num2`. You can do this like:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE *, num1 + num2 AS num3:int ;
DESCRIBE B; 
B: {num1:int, num2:int, num3:int}
```

Used like this, the `*` operator generates all fields.

Comment: for more info: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#expressions search for "Project-Range Expressions"